# mysql_fetch_array returns only one row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to export each row of my SQL query as a variable and print it with TCPDF. Currently it returns only one row.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,betrag,notiz,datum, CASE WHEN entnahme = '0' THEN 'Einzahlung' ELSE 'Auszahlung' END AS entnahme_text FROM bestand WHERE datum >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00' ORDER BY datum DESC;"$
$tbl .= '<tr><td>ID</td><td>Richtung</td><td>Betrag</td><td>Notiz</td><td>Datum</td></tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $entnahme = $row['entnahme_text'];
  $betrag = $row['betrag'];
  $notiz = $row['notiz'];
  $datum = $row['datum'];
}

$tbl .= '<tr><td>' . $id . '</td><td>' .$entnahme. '</td><td>' . $betrag . '</td><td>' .$notiz. '</td><td>' .$datum. '</td></tr>';

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl1 . $aktuellesdatum . $date . $br  . $tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output('', 'I');
```

---

Thanks, now i've already get a useful output as pdf.
But if I add $notiz (note) and $datum (date) the output will be blank.

The note field is type "text" in sql. Does anybody know, why it cannot output the "text" and "date" column?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,betrag,notiz,datum, CASE WHEN entnahme = '0' THEN 'Einzahlung' ELSE 'Auszahlung' END AS entnahme_text FROM bestand WHERE datum >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00' ORDER BY datum DESC;");
$tbl .= '<tr><td>ID</td><td>Richtung</td><td>Betrag</td><td>Notiz</td><td>Datum</td></tr>';
$tblcontent = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $entnahme = $row['entnahme_text'];
  $betrag = $row['betrag'];
  $notiz = $row['notiz'];
  $datum = $row['datum'];
  $tblcontent .= "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$entnahme</td><td>$betrag</td></tr>";
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xj4q.jpg)

---

I've tried it like this.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $entnahme = $row['entnahme_text'];
  $betrag = $row['betrag'];
  $notiz = $row['notiz'];
  $datum = $row['datum'];
  $tblcontent = '<tr><td>id</td><td>betrag</td></tr>';
}

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl1 . $aktuellesdatum . $date . $br  . $tbl_header . $tbl . $tblcontent . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');


$tbl1 is used as title in the pdf
$aktuellesdatum text for current date
$date for date
$tbl_header is used to create the table (<table border="1"><h6></h6>)
$tbl for the first description row
$tblcontent for the output of the sql-query
$tbl_footer to close the table (</table>)
```

With this code it looks like this
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xj4q.jpg)

Comment: `WHERE datum >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00' ORDER BY datum DESC;"$` <- whats this dollar sign doing here?

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks, that was my fault I will remove it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely find it is fetching all of the data, but you are only concatenating it outside the loop.  So move this inside the loop to use all of the data...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $entnahme = $row['entnahme_text'];
  $betrag = $row['betrag'];
  $notiz = $row['notiz'];
  $datum = $row['datum'];
  $tbl .= '<tr><td>' . $id . '</td><td>' .$entnahme. '</td><td>' . $betrag . '</td><td>' .$notiz. '</td><td>' .$datum. '</td></tr>';
}
```

You could get rid of the interim variables and just insert the data directly which is slightly more efficient...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $tbl .= '<tr><td>' . $row['id'] . '</td><td>' .
         $row['entnahme_text']. '</td><td>' . $row['betrag'] . 
         '</td><td>' .$row['notiz']. '</td><td>' .$row['datum']. 
         '</td></tr>';
}
```

I think you need to change the first line of `$tbl` (remove the `.` in `.=`)...

```
$tbl = '<tr><td>ID</td><td>Richtung</td><td>Betrag</td><td>Notiz</td><td>Datum</td></tr>';
```

This will make sure that it starts with the headers and then the `.=` in each loop will add on each line.

Comment: Thanks therfore, if I replace while with your version the PDF Output is completely empty. Also, if I remove the dot between "$tbl .=" it still shows one entry. But TCPDF should print all entries. $pdf->writeHTML($tbl1 . $aktuellesdatum . $date . $br  . $tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');

Comment: I've added the comment to the answer - try it just with this change rather than how you've got in your answer.